# Read sms (and other content) programatically on Android

Tags: android, api, sms

I'm looking at writing an app which will use text present on a user's device to generate other text - ie, read through all SMSs on the device, parse this somehow, then do something with this data (ie, a word-cloud of common phrases or similar).

I see there is a way to access the SMSs on the device, but it looks a little ropey:

[Android 2.2 Read SMS Inbox messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238567/android-2-2-read-sms-inbox-messages)

Are there other ways? I think I read somewhere that this would fail on some devices - any info on that? Any suggestions for other sources of (text) data which I could consider pulling from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, using a content provider is the only way to access text messages on android. You should do some more research though. I think once you get more comfortable with the ContentProvider interface it will feel pretty easy. In fact, I recommend you read [this article in the android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) about ContentProviders. Perhaps that will help you.

Comment: In addition, dont forget the permissions :P